# Unable to pass ActiveMQ configuration in Quarkus native build with Camel setup

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, quarkus, quarkus-native

I am getting the following errors while passing ActiveMQ properties in the broker URL in Quarkus native build and Camel setup.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {transport.initialReconnectDelay=1000, transport.timeout=5000, transport.maxReconnectAttempts=5}

Invalid socket parameters: {enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2}, continuing to retry.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of this issue. This is related to Quarkus native build and reflection. At startup, the framework tries to set properties using reflection. After adding the following into reflectconfig.json, everything is working as expected.

```
"name": "org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo",
"allDeclaredConstructors": true,
"allPublicConstructors": true,
"allDeclaredMethods": true,
"allPublicMethods": true,
"allDeclaredClasses": true,
"allPublicClasses": true

"name": "org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport",
"allDeclaredConstructors": true,
"allPublicConstructors": true,
"allDeclaredMethods": true,
"allPublicMethods": true,
"allDeclaredClasses": true,
"allPublicClasses": true

"name": "sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl",
"allDeclaredConstructors": true,
"allPublicConstructors": true,
"allDeclaredMethods": true,
"allPublicMethods": true,
"allDeclaredClasses": true,
"allPublicClasses": true
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, @Abhishek Kumar. A Camel Quarkus issue was filed for this. You may follow the progress there https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues/3809

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in using vanilla Activemq 5 client with quarkus native mode, e.g.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

following configuration works:

src/main/resources/reflection-config.json

```
[
{
    "name": "org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
},
{
    "name": "org.apache.activemq.openwire.v12.MarshallerFactory",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
},
{
    "name": "org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormatFactory",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
},
{
    "name": "org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
},
{
    "name": "org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
},
{
    "name": "sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
}]
```

src/main/resources/resources-config.json

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "pattern": ".*/services/org/apache/activemq.*"
    }
  ]
}
```

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json, -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json
```